# Posting blog entries in screenplay format

Tags: posts, blog, formatting

Recently I've been working on a series of scripts and wanted to publish them on my site as blog entries, largely because having them just sitting on my hard drive with only a few people reading them doesn't do me any good.  The trouble is, screenplay format is pretty distinct and doesn't play well with most text fields I've experimented with.

What are my options?  Is there a plugin that can help me with this?  Would it be possible to post the PDFs as an entry and they can be displayed without making the font so small as to be unreadable?  I'm not especially good at HTML coding.  I can learn it if I have to, but if there's an easier way that doesn't involve having to copy/paste all the text from the original documents and re-format it through HTML manually, that would save me a lot of time.

Comment: Not all of us are sure what you mean by a screenplay format, can you provide examples, including what you've done so far and how that worked out? As a side note, questions that are plugin recommendations get closed here as off topic/out of scope

Comment: I was not aware of the plugins thing, thank you.  Screenplay format is always in Courier New (don't ask why) and dialog has to be constrained to different margins than the rest of the text (1 inch deeper on either side).  There are also strict guidelines for scene headers, where the name of the character speaking goes, etc.  Does that help?

Comment: There's the [Scrippets plug-in](http://fountain.io/scrippets), developed by screenwriter John August's team for his blog and using his 'fountain' mark-up language. Tools do exist to try and generate fountain from screenplay PDFs too.

Comment: Huh. I don't know whether I posted my answer before or after you commented, Rup :p

Answer (score 0):

This "scrippets for Wordpress" plugin worked well for me, writing screenplay content in fountain format:

http://fountain.io/scrippets